# Publishing map->odom transform using custom localization and SLAM algorithms

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am writing my own FastSLAM and Monte-Carlo localization algorithms and I am trying to figure out how to calculate the map->odom transform. From what I understand, my SLAM and localization algorithm will give the transform from the map frame to the base_link frame  when given odometry data calculated in the odom frame. I have seen that AMCL and Gmapping publish the transform from the odom frame to the map frame, but I am not sure of how to calculate this once I have the map to base_link transform from the SLAM or localization algorithm.

Would I assume that the transform from the odometry data is "correct", create transformation matrices for T_(map->base_link) and T_(odom->base_link) and then say:

T_(map->odom) = T_(map->base_link) * T_(odom->base_link)^-1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401747/publishing-map-%3Eodom-transform-using-custom-localization-and-slam-algorithms/) by [onishly](https://answers.ros.org/users/106655/onishly/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-06-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Though not all the same but similar for the localization and SLAM algorithms. The TF publishing in GMapping is easier to understand.

[slam_gmapping/gmapping/src/slam_gmapping.cpp](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/blob/0835d19c69dae36c98b8fa337f4cc2162bdbaf0c/gmapping/src/slam_gmapping.cpp#L641)

```
map_to_odom_ = (odom_to_laser * laser_to_map).inverse();
```

The following is the most frequently used and I am sure it is correct.

> T_(map->odom) = (T_(odom->base_link) *
> T_(map->base_link)^-1)^-1

T_(odom->base_link) is given by your odometry (either encoders or VO or anything else), T_(map->base_link) is calculated by the "localization" algorithm. Both are known.

---

Originally posted by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) with karma: 710 on 2022-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, your matrix multiply is correct. You can eliminate the inverse() by asking tf2 for `T(base_link->odom)`.

This calculation is valid for any arbitrary value of `T(odom->base_link)`, so "correctness" is not a concern.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-06-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1